# How to convert Asp.Net dataset to xml format and send as a request to server and obtain result in the [.aspx] page

Tags: asp.net

i have a [.Aspx] page from which i have to send a request from  three textboxes to the server

in the [xml] format  and the server should connect to the database and fetch the data from the

database and display result in the [.Aspx] page please send the code for this question

immedietly as i am waiting for it

```
                                                                             Thanks
                                                                             Regards
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok.

If i am not wrong you need to fetch data from database depending upon 3 textbox values.

1: You can store the value in 3 variables in the code behind

string strTextbox1 = txtTextBox1.Text; // Get the 1st text box value

// similarly get the value 3 textboxes.

2: Create a connection to the database

SqlConnection objConn = new SqlConnection();

objConn.ConnectionString = "" // Give your connection string.

string strQuery = "" // Write your select query here

// Create a sql command

SqlCommand objCom = new SqlCommand(strQuery );

//Create a datatable

DataTable objData = new DataTable();

SqlDataAdapter objAdap = new SqlDataAdapter(objCom );

objAdap.Fill(objData );

// Now you have the required data from database in objData.

But 1st please tell me why do you need XML??

Comment: Hi  i need [xml] to send as a request  so that there may be no chance of hacking data between client and server

Comment: @user1506404 By sending xml you cann't stop user to tamper data in client side. Anyway if you rally want to send xml then on the client side create the xml string and store it in hidden field. Then access the hidden field value in server side.